# Phonon calculations stopped but my computer says it's still running

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, phonons

[image]
[image]

I have this after typing an htop and all of the CPUs are used but my output file stopped updating 3 hours ago like this:

[image]

Should I kill this process? I started this calculation yesterday at 16:00 and it stopped after 21 hours :(

Comment: My recommendations is: just kill the calculations, save the log files, and then run it again. If the new calculation does the same, kill it and compare the logs files with the previous one. Also, try an already n=known working example.

Comment: How can I save log files? Maybe I've discovered the error but I do not know how to solve it: in the .out file it states :"Waiting for input... Reading input from standard input", could it be?

Comment: I don't have a direct answer, but according to the [QE troubleshooting manual](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/pw_user_guide/node21.html) it's likely your parallel execution has failed on one or more nodes. You might see if you can run the calculation (or a smaller version) in serial; that may at least give you more information about the error.